# Neo4j php addLabels

Tags: php, neo4j

I am beginner with Neo4j Rest API. I  am using [Everyman](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp) php library to develop my application. I have problem with creating node with labels.

```
use Everyman\Neo4j\Client,
    Everyman\Neo4j\Transport,
    Everyman\Neo4j\Node,
    Everyman\Neo4j\Relationship;
use Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher;

public function indexAction()
{  
    $client = new Client('localhost', 7474);
    $user = new Node($client);
    $user->setProperty('name', 'Rohan Chingula');
    $user->save()->addLabels(array('Users'));
}
```

while I run code I am getting

> /var/www/zf2-tutorial/vendor/everyman/neo4jphp/lib/Everyman/Neo4j/Command/SetLabels.php:43
>   Message:
>   Cannot set a non-label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$userLabel = $client->makeLabel('Users');
$user->save()->addLabels(array($userLabel));
```

`User::addLabels` expects an array of Label objects.

https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Labels#wiki-adding-labels-to-a-node

Aside: if adding a bare string as a label is functionality you would like to see, please submit a feature request: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/issues

Comment: Hey Josh Adell, In the above example , I am creating the node using $client = new Client('localhost', 7474);
$user = new Node($client);                                             This will not make a custom node. Such as actor, user, movie. I want to make user node , actor node ect (Custom node name not like 234, 34 ec etetra). How do i get this. Could you please give me example ?.;

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP coder, but a quick look at the source suggests you should be passing an array of Label objects not strings. Your code is not using Everyman\Neo4j\Label

```
  $labelSet = implode(':', array_map(function ($label) {
    if (!($label instanceof Label)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cannot set a non-label");
```

Comment: I already included Everyman\Neo4j\Label in my code . But result is same. I don't know  why this is happening to me . If you go to Everyman\Neo4j\Node.php then you will see addLabels function at line 116. So i think  we don't need  Everyman\Neo4j\Label . Mike could suggest me with example how could i resolve this.